# Neo4j - Unable to create Relationship entities

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to insert the relationships between two nodes in Neo4j. I am using the Neo4J(2.1.8 Community) & spring-data-neo4j(3.3.0.RELEASE).

I am using trying to create the Employee-Manager relationship. This relationship entity is Report. (Both class are given below)

But when I am trying to save the relation ship

```
Employee manager = new Employee("Dev_manager", "Management");
Employee developer = new Employee("Developer", "Development");
developer.setReportsTo(manager);
developer.relatedTo(manager, "REPORTS_TO")
employeeRepository.save(developer);
```

I am getting exception as

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: RELATIONSHIP[0] has no property with propertyKey="**type**".; nested exception is org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: RELATIONSHIP[0] has no property with propertyKey="**type**".

Can any one please help me that what is exactly wrong in this code.

The same code works after I change the type of relations in Employee as

```
@RelatedToVia(type = "REPORT_TO", elementClass = Report.class, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
```

**Note:** I am using [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#tutorial_relationships) reference for this tutorial.

**Employee.java** class

```
@NodeEntity
public class Employee {

@GraphId
private Long id;
private String name;
private String department;

@Fetch
@RelatedTo(type = "REPORTS_TO")
private Employee reportsTo; //Employee reports to some employee (i.e. Manager).

@Fetch
@RelatedTo(type = "REPORTS_TO", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
Set<Employee> directReport; //All the employees who reports to this particular this employee.

@Fetch
@RelatedToVia(type = "REPORTS_TO", elementClass = Report.class, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
Set<Report> relations = new HashSet<Report>(); // All the incoming relationship entities.
//*** Constructor, Getter-setters and other methods...
}
```

**Report.java** class

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "REPORTS_TO")
public class Report {

@GraphId
private Long id;
private String title;

@Fetch
@StartNode
private Employee child;

@Fetch
@EndNode
private Employee parent;
//*** Constructor, Getter-setters and other methods...
}
```

**Update: **
I have created 2 relations using this class structure. And I got the below result.
[image]

It looks like it creates 2 relations between the node. 1 is empty relation using reportsTo(i.e. REPORTS_TO) and another relation using the relations(i.e. REPORT_TO). Can anyone please update why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the different between: `relations` and `directReport`?

I think SDN is just confused with all the duplicate listing of relationships?

Esp. if they are once declared as light relationships without type and once as relationship-entities.

I think for this case it is much clearer and easier to use

`template.createRelationshipBetween(employee, manager, "REPORTS_TO");`

Or just create, populate and save the relationship-entity `Report`.

Otherwise you have to make sure that all collections on all sides are consistent with each other.

Comment: As per [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#accessing_related_entities) section, we can use **@RelatedTo** to retrieve the nodes for incoming relations. Just like **cast** in **Movies class**.
And as per [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#accessing_the_relationship_entities) section, we can use retrieve the relationship entities with **@RelatedToVia** annotation.
But I am unable to do.

Comment: It is about creating relationships. Either you have to consistently add it to all the collections on both sides or do it via the methods mentioned above.